# Insert Into and multiple union with 3 Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS-Access. I have a table A looks like :

```
 id isin    typ1    typ2                                                                                 
 1  aa      typA    typB                                                                                 
 2  bb      typD    typC
```

a Table C Like:

```
id  isin   code1   assetName   BBweight
1   aa       x        x           x
2   bb       x        x           x
```

...  ..      ..        ..         ..

I need to insert both tables into table B that looks like:

```
 ID  isin   fld   fldValue  BBweight   code1  assetName                                                          
 1   aa     typ1     typA       w1       x       x                                                                                 
 2   aa     typ2     typB       w2       x       x                                                                                 
 3   bb     typ1     typD       ...     ...     ...                                                                                 
 4   bb     typ2     typC       ...     ...     ...
```

What's the SQL string, compatible with MS-Access, that I can use?

This is the string i'm using that doesn't work:

sql = "insert into B (isin, code1, assetName, BBweight, fld, [fldValue]) " _
& "SELECT isin, code1, assetName, BBweight, fld, [fldValue] from " _
& "(select isin, code1, assetName, BBweight from C) " _
& "Union " _
& "(select isin, 'typ1' as fld, typ1 as [fldValue] from A " _
& "Union " _
& "select isin, 'typ2' as fld, typ2 as [fldValue] from A) as R "

Comment: Do you have code to post along with the data/output you're expecting that isn't working quite just right?

Comment: sql = "insert into B (isin, code1, assetName, BBweight, fld, [fldValue]) " _
        & "SELECT isin, code1, assetName, BBweight, fld, [fldValue] from " _
        & "(select isin, code1, assetName, BBweight from C) " _
        & "Union " _
        & "(select isin, 'typ2' as fld, typ2 as [fldValue] from A " _
        & "Union " _
        & "select isin, 'typ3' as fld, typ3 as [fldValue] from A) as R "

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a helpful descriptor. Please describe what actually happens. Errors? Undesired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
insert into B (isin, fld, fldvalue, BBweight, code1, assetName)
select isin, fld, fldvalue, BBweight, code1, assetName from
  (select isin, "typ1" as fld, typ1 as fldvalue from A
  union all
  select isin, "typ2" as fld, typ2 from A) as R
inner join C on R.isin = C.isin
order by R.isin, fld
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a tutorial with vb](https://www.xylos.com/en/learning/blog/tip-7-save-time-processing-data-excel-vba) if you're trying to be fancy with code, but the SQL you're looking for is a JOIN.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Table A
JOIN Table B on a.id = b.id and a.isin = b.isin
```

StackOverflow is here to help when you've *hit a roadblock*, not build it for you; please show us your attempts and your specific issue, with code, after you've tried it a few times.

**EDIT**:

Thank you for providing your attempt! I see I skipped over a key element of the requirement. You nearly had it; you want to JOIN against your UNION'd statement, not UNION again. This is the clean SQL for it, that you need to put into your VB:

```sql
SELECT 
  newTableA.*,
  tableC.code1,
  tableC.assetName,
  tableC.BBWeight
FROM 
    (
      SELECT    isin,    'typ1' as fld,    typ1 as fldValue FROM tableA
      UNION 
      SELECT    isin,    'typ2' as fld,    typ2 as fldValue FROM tableA
    ) newTableA
JOIN TableC on newTableA.isin = TableC.isin
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d00e0f/6/0)

Comment: i do not think you read  the question properly. Columns typ1 e typ2 in A become rows in B, but not for C... Your ansewer doesn't help. I posted my trying now

Comment: I see I  missed a key element; I have updated my answer @Giovanni